# How can Input variables into bash commands to be run inline? Debug bash ctrlZ?

Tags: bash, variables, sed, expansion

UPDATE: I learned input variables can be accessed with commands like xargs getopts() and using $@ $% and $# as well as !* for the output of last command

To clarify the question when I run a command like

**`rep="replace" && echo foobar | sed -e 's/.*/${rep}/'`**

**the text is not replaced with variable contents** I tried wrapping in brackets quotes and percent signs. I also tried seds insert command.

Any there any methods to debug or step thru Bash? I noticed pressing ctrl Z rather than ctrl C lets me see return values.

**For those who like to say "duplicate" rather than answer; These posts didnt help me:**

[Replace string variable with string variable using Sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560515/replace-string-variable-with-string-variable-using-sed)

["sed" special characters handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890230/sed-special-characters-handling)

Other notes:
*//WARNING//* in this command I set an alias that runs itself is that bad practice? I think I was trying codegolf code and ending up making directories with [[ in my $home directory on live disc so careful on your install.

```
alias a="espeak $1" && b=$($a) //the b part runs it and can be omited
```

for example this works fine after the alias of a
**seq 11 -1 0 |a**

**alias countDown="seq $1 -1 0|a"** doesn't work with **countDown 10** as an example run.

This method omits sed command:
@destenson post at [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern)

```
inputvar="foobar" && txt2replace="oo" && txt2replacewith="rench" && outputvar="${inputvar//"$txt2replace"/"$txt2replacewith"}" && echo $outputvar && echo $outputvar|a
```

helped

Comment: does the string $rep contain escape characters how do I debug and see them? $rep|hd? shows me an extra '.' char but so does echo "replace"|hd

Comment: Using an alias is bad practice whether or not it is recursive.

Comment: Pressing ctrl-Z does something very different than ctrl-C, so the behavior is different.  One suspends the process (by sending SIGTSTP), the other kills it (by sending SIGINT).  You seem surprised that they do different things.

Comment: I wasn't using quotes and that was THE PROBLEM I guess.

Comment: One question per question, please. I added a bunch of duplicates but you might want to create a new question which asks a *single* question if you need more guidance on the debugging topic in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the variable out of the single quotes:

```
rep="replace" && echo foobar | sed -e 's/.*/'${rep}'/'
```

Double quotes are fine:

```
rep="replace" && echo foobar | sed -e 's/.*/'"${rep}"'/'
```

Comment: That worked but is confusing. so what happens with $rep or %$rep% and ${rep} how can I debug bash?

Comment: $(rep="echo thxM8" && echo foobar | sed -e 's/.*/'"${rep}"'/')|espeak

Comment: You can debug it like this: `rep="replace" && echo "echo foobar | sed -e 's/.*/'"${rep}"/"`

Comment: I meant is there a way to debug bash like by alias [="test && $(echo ${1})"